# org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$SlowItem exception in basic NetBeans plugin

Tags: java, netbeans, plugins

I followed a tutorial to build a simple plugin for NetBeans v 7.3.1 ... I know this is an older version of NetBeans but I'm restricted by the software my employer insists on using.

All I have is a simple plugin that loads a toolbar item that consists of a button.  But when I run the plugin, I always get the same exception alert in a popup:

```
A org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$SlowItem exception has occurred.
Please report this at [blah blah website blah blah log file created]
```

This message hasn't been helpful solving the problem.  Here is the log file, which as a Java n00b I've been unable to decipher or understand what is going on in it well enough to figure out why I'm getting this error.  And there's little to no info I've been able to find in searches.  If I'm reading it right (I'm sure I'm not reading it right) then the error is happening in .jar files where I can't do anything about it.  So is there anything I can hope to do to ship a plugin that will run without throwing exceptions?  Workaround?  Something stupid I missed as a n00b?

```
SEVERE [org.openide.util.RequestProcessor]: Error in RequestProcessor org.openide.loaders.FolderInstance$1R
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openide.util.Exceptions$AnnException.getMessage(Exceptions.java:238)
    at org.openide.util.Exceptions$AnnException.toString(Exceptions.java:321)
    at java.util.Objects.toString(Objects.java:159)
    at java.lang.Throwable.initCause(Throwable.java:457)
    at org.openide.util.Exceptions$AnnException.findOrCreate0(Exceptions.java:279)
    at org.openide.util.Exceptions$AnnException.findOrCreate0(Exceptions.java:286)
    at org.openide.util.Exceptions$AnnException.findOrCreate0(Exceptions.java:286)
    at org.openide.util.Exceptions$AnnException.findOrCreate0(Exceptions.java:286)
    at org.openide.util.Exceptions$AnnException.findOrCreate0(Exceptions.java:286)
    at org.openide.util.Exceptions$AnnException.findOrCreate(Exceptions.java:256)
    at org.openide.util.Exceptions.attachMessage(Exceptions.java:85)
    at org.openide.loaders.InstanceSupport.instanceClass(InstanceSupport.java:157)
    at org.openide.loaders.InstanceDataObject$Ser.instanceClass(InstanceDataObject.java:1338)
    at org.openide.loaders.InstanceDataObject.instanceClass(InstanceDataObject.java:809)
    at org.openide.awt.MenuBar$LazyMenu$MenuFolder.acceptCookie(MenuBar.java:808)
    at org.openide.loaders.FolderInstance.acceptDataObject(FolderInstance.java:419)
    at org.openide.loaders.FolderInstance.defaultProcessObjects(FolderInstance.java:795)
    at org.openide.loaders.FolderInstance.access$000(FolderInstance.java:103)
    at org.openide.loaders.FolderInstance$1R.init(FolderInstance.java:693)
    at org.openide.loaders.FolderInstance$1R.run(FolderInstance.java:720)
Caused: org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$SlowItem: task failed due to
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.schedule(RequestProcessor.java:1473)
    at org.openide.loaders.FolderInstance.processObjects(FolderInstance.java:768)
    at org.openide.loaders.FolderInstance$Listener.finished(FolderInstance.java:1052)
    at org.openide.loaders.FolderList.createBoth(FolderList.java:923)
    at org.openide.loaders.FolderList.getObjects(FolderList.java:608)
    at org.openide.loaders.FolderList.access$200(FolderList.java:77)
    at org.openide.loaders.FolderList$ListTask.computeResult(FolderList.java:1007)
    at org.openide.loaders.FolderList$ListTask.run(FolderList.java:983)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1432)
[catch] at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2044)
WARNING [org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader]: Will not load class org.netbeans.modules.editor.NbCodeFoldingAction arbitrarily from one of ModuleCL@183d64f7[org.netbeans.modules.editor] and ModuleCL@52954826[com.mycompany.TrestleLauncher] starting from SystemClassLoader[263 modules]; see http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqModuleCCE
INFO [org.openide.loaders.FolderInstance.Menu.View]
Cannot get class for MultiFileObject@26bf742[Menu/View/org-netbeans-modules-editor-NbCodeFoldingAction.instance] defined by [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%207.3.1/ide/modules/org-netbeans-modules-editor.jar!/org/netbeans/modules/editor/resources/layer.xml]
Cannot get class for MultiFileObject@26bf742[Menu/View/org-netbeans-modules-editor-NbCodeFoldingAction.instance] defined by [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%207.3.1/ide/modules/org-netbeans-modules-editor.jar!/org/netbeans/modules/editor/resources/layer.xml]
Caused: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openide.util.Exceptions$AnnException.getMessage(Exceptions.java:238)
    at org.openide.util.Exceptions$AnnException.toString(Exceptions.java:321)
    at java.util.Objects.toString(Objects.java:159)
    at java.lang.Throwable.initCause(Throwable.java:457)
    at org.openide.util.Exceptions$AnnException.findOrCreate0(Exceptions.java:279)
    at org.openide.util.Exceptions$AnnException.findOrCreate(Exceptions.java:256)
    at org.openide.util.Exceptions.attachMessage(Exceptions.java:85)
    at org.openide.loaders.InstanceSupport.findClass(InstanceSupport.java:506)
    at org.openide.loaders.InstanceSupport.instanceClass(InstanceSupport.java:148)
Caused: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: From file: MultiFileObject@26bf742[Menu/View/org-netbeans-modules-editor-NbCodeFoldingAction.instance] due to
    at org.openide.loaders.InstanceSupport.instanceClass(InstanceSupport.java:162)
    at org.openide.loaders.InstanceDataObject$Ser.instanceClass(InstanceDataObject.java:1338)
    at org.openide.loaders.InstanceDataObject.instanceClass(InstanceDataObject.java:809)
    at org.openide.awt.MenuBar$LazyMenu$MenuFolder.acceptCookie(MenuBar.java:808)
[catch] at org.openide.loaders.FolderInstance.acceptDataObject(FolderInstance.java:419)
    at org.openide.loaders.FolderInstance.defaultProcessObjects(FolderInstance.java:795)
    at org.openide.loaders.FolderInstance.access$000(FolderInstance.java:103)
    at org.openide.loaders.FolderInstance$1R.init(FolderInstance.java:693)
    at org.openide.loaders.FolderInstance$1R.run(FolderInstance.java:720)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1432)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2044)
ALL [null]: Cannot get class for MultiFileObject@26bf742[Menu/View/org-netbeans-modules-editor-NbCodeFoldingAction.instance] defined by [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%207.3.1/ide/modules/org-netbeans-modules-editor.jar!/org/netbeans/modules/editor/resources/layer.xml]
WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.editor.settings.storage.keybindings.KeyMapsStorage]: The keybinding 'A-MOUSE_WHEEL_UP' in Editors/Keybindings/NetBeans/Defaults/org-netbeans-modules-editor-keybindings.xml may not work correctly on Mac. Keybindings starting with Alt or Ctrl should be coded with latin capital letters 'O' or 'D' respectively. For details see org.openide.util.Utilities.stringToKey().
WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.editor.settings.storage.keybindings.KeyMapsStorage]: The keybinding 'A-MOUSE_WHEEL_DOWN' in Editors/Keybindings/NetBeans/Defaults/org-netbeans-modules-editor-keybindings.xml may not work correctly on Mac. Keybindings starting with Alt or Ctrl should be coded with latin capital letters 'O' or 'D' respectively. For details see org.openide.util.Utilities.stringToKey().
WARNING [org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader]: Will not load class org.netbeans.modules.editor.MainMenuAction$GoToSourceAction arbitrarily from one of ModuleCL@183d64f7[org.netbeans.modules.editor] and ModuleCL@52954826[com.mycompany.TrestleLauncher] starting from SystemClassLoader[263 modules]; see http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqModuleCCE
INFO [org.openide.loaders.FolderInstance.Menu.GoTo]
Cannot get class for MultiFileObject@7e5308ff[Menu/GoTo/org-netbeans-modules-editor-MainMenuAction$GoToSourceAction.instance] defined by [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%207.3.1/ide/modules/org-netbeans-modules-editor.jar!/org/netbeans/modules/editor/resources/layer.xml]
Cannot get class for MultiFileObject@7e5308ff[Menu/GoTo/org-netbeans-modules-editor-MainMenuAction$GoToSourceAction.instance] defined by [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%207.3.1/ide/modules/org-netbeans-modules-editor.jar!/org/netbeans/modules/editor/resources/layer.xml]
Caused: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openide.util.Exceptions$AnnException.getMessage(Exceptions.java:238)
    at org.openide.util.Exceptions$AnnException.toString(Exceptions.java:321)
    at java.util.Objects.toString(Objects.java:159)
    at java.lang.Throwable.initCause(Throwable.java:457)
    at org.openide.util.Exceptions$AnnException.findOrCreate0(Exceptions.java:279)
    at org.openide.util.Exceptions$AnnException.findOrCreate(Exceptions.java:256)
    at org.openide.util.Exceptions.attachMessage(Exceptions.java:85)
    at org.openide.loaders.InstanceSupport.findClass(InstanceSupport.java:506)
    at org.openide.loaders.InstanceSupport.instanceClass(InstanceSupport.java:148)
Caused: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: From file: MultiFileObject@7e5308ff[Menu/GoTo/org-netbeans-modules-editor-MainMenuAction$GoToSourceAction.instance] due to
    at org.openide.loaders.InstanceSupport.instanceClass(InstanceSupport.java:162)
    at org.openide.loaders.InstanceDataObject$Ser.instanceClass(InstanceDataObject.java:1338)
    at org.openide.loaders.InstanceDataObject.instanceClass(InstanceDataObject.java:809)
    at org.openide.awt.MenuBar$LazyMenu$MenuFolder.acceptCookie(MenuBar.java:808)
[catch] at org.openide.loaders.FolderInstance.acceptDataObject(FolderInstance.java:419)
    at org.openide.loaders.FolderInstance.defaultProcessObjects(FolderInstance.java:795)
    at org.openide.loaders.FolderInstance.access$000(FolderInstance.java:103)
    at org.openide.loaders.FolderInstance$1R.init(FolderInstance.java:693)
    at org.openide.loaders.FolderInstance$1R.run(FolderInstance.java:720)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1432)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2044)
ALL [null]: Cannot get class for MultiFileObject@7e5308ff[Menu/GoTo/org-netbeans-modules-editor-MainMenuAction$GoToSourceAction.instance] defined by [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%207.3.1/ide/modules/org-netbeans-modules-editor.jar!/org/netbeans/modules/editor/resources/layer.xml]
WARNING [org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader]: Will not load class org.netbeans.modules.editor.MainMenuAction$GoToSuperAction arbitrarily from one of ModuleCL@183d64f7[org.netbeans.modules.editor] and ModuleCL@52954826[com.mycompany.TrestleLauncher] starting from SystemClassLoader[263 modules]; see http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqModuleCCE
INFO [org.openide.loaders.FolderInstance.Menu.GoTo]
Cannot get class for MultiFileObject@210198eb[Menu/GoTo/org-netbeans-modules-editor-MainMenuAction$GoToSuperAction.instance] defined by [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%207.3.1/ide/modules/org-netbeans-modules-editor.jar!/org/netbeans/modules/editor/resources/layer.xml]
Cannot get class for MultiFileObject@210198eb[Menu/GoTo/org-netbeans-modules-editor-MainMenuAction$GoToSuperAction.instance] defined by [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%207.3.1/ide/modules/org-netbeans-modules-editor.jar!/org/netbeans/modules/editor/resources/layer.xml]
Caused: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openide.util.Exceptions$AnnException.getMessage(Exceptions.java:238)
    at org.openide.util.Exceptions$AnnException.toString(Exceptions.java:321)
    at java.util.Objects.toString(Objects.java:159)
    at java.lang.Throwable.initCause(Throwable.java:457)
    at org.openide.util.Exceptions$AnnException.findOrCreate0(Exceptions.java:279)
    at org.openide.util.Exceptions$AnnException.findOrCreate(Exceptions.java:256)
    at org.openide.util.Exceptions.attachMessage(Exceptions.java:85)
    at org.openide.loaders.InstanceSupport.findClass(InstanceSupport.java:506)
    at org.openide.loaders.InstanceSupport.instanceClass(InstanceSupport.java:148)
Caused: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: From file: MultiFileObject@210198eb[Menu/GoTo/org-netbeans-modules-editor-MainMenuAction$GoToSuperAction.instance] due to
    at org.openide.loaders.InstanceSupport.instanceClass(InstanceSupport.java:162)
    at org.openide.loaders.InstanceDataObject$Ser.instanceClass(InstanceDataObject.java:1338)
    at org.openide.loaders.InstanceDataObject.instanceClass(InstanceDataObject.java:809)
    at org.openide.awt.MenuBar$LazyMenu$MenuFolder.acceptCookie(MenuBar.java:808)
[catch] at org.openide.loaders.FolderInstance.acceptDataObject(FolderInstance.java:419)
    at org.openide.loaders.FolderInstance.defaultProcessObjects(FolderInstance.java:795)
    at org.openide.loaders.FolderInstance.access$000(FolderInstance.java:103)
    at org.openide.loaders.FolderInstance$1R.init(FolderInstance.java:693)
    at org.openide.loaders.FolderInstance$1R.run(FolderInstance.java:720)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1432)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2044)
ALL [null]: Cannot get class for MultiFileObject@210198eb[Menu/GoTo/org-netbeans-modules-editor-MainMenuAction$GoToSuperAction.instance] defined by [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%207.3.1/ide/modules/org-netbeans-modules-editor.jar!/org/netbeans/modules/editor/resources/layer.xml]
WARNING [org.openide.filesystems.Ordering]: Not all children in Menu/Window/ marked with the position attribute: [Other], but some are: [org-netbeans-modules-project-ui-logical-tab-action.shadow, org-netbeans-modules-project-ui-physical-tab-action.shadow, org-netbeans-modules-favorites-View.shadow, org-netbeans-core-ide-ServicesTabAction.shadow, org-netbeans-modules-tasklist-ui-TaskListAction.shadow, ShowPaletteAction.shadow, org-netbeans-core-windows-actions-GlobalPropertiesAction.shadow, Output, Navigator, Debug, Versioning, Web, SwitchToRecentDocumentAction.shadow, ProgressListAction.shadow, Separator3.instance, ConfigureWindow, org-netbeans-core-windows-actions-ResetWindowsAction.shadow, Separator4.instance, CloseWindowAction.shadow, CloseAllDocumentsAction.shadow, CloseAllButThisAction.shadow, DocumentsAction.shadow]
WARNING [org.netbeans.TopSecurityManager]: use of system property netbeans.user has been obsoleted in favor of InstalledFileLocator/Places at org.netbeans.modules.uihandler.Installer.logsDirectory(Installer.java:840)
INFO [org.netbeans.core.netigso.Netigso]: bundle org.eclipse.osgi@3.8.0.v20120529-1548 256
INFO [org.netbeans.core.netigso.Netigso]: bundle org.eclipse.osgi@3.8.0.v20120529-1548 stopped
INFO [org.netbeans.core.netigso.Netigso]: bundle org.eclipse.osgi@3.8.0.v20120529-1548 stopped
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have been a result of adding a library package via Wrapped .JAR that didn't need to be added (or more accurately, needed to be added using a more correct method).  Instead of finding, downloading, and depending on Wrapped .JAR files to account for dependencies, I needed to add module dependencies by name (not by package) in NetBeans.